# Need to retrieve the json key value as null if key not present at the node

Tags: karate

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": 0
  },
  "values": [
    {
      "d": "WERTY",
      "e": "details",
      "f": [
        {
          "addressId": "vvvv",
          "address": "ffff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "d": "ZXCVB",
      "e": "details"
    },
    {
      "d": "ASDFG",
      "e": "details",
      "f": [
        {
          "addressId": "vvvv",
          "address": "xxxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After getting the response from restassured, I am trying to fetch the values of a particular key with JsonPath.
I am using:

```
         responseBody.jsonPath().getList("values.f.address)
```

This is returning me a list - ["ffff","xxxx"]
I want to get - ["ffff",null,"xxxx"]

Is it possible to achieve this with Karate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JsonPath = values[0].f[0].address
```

If you are using `validatableResonse` then you can use:

```
String res_str = Response.extract().jsonPath().getString("values[0].f[0].address");
```

The response should be of `ValidatableResponse` type.

Answer (score 0):

It won't return you `null` for that absent item, because field `address` is actually not present in the response body.

Comment: Hi @Villa_7, thanks for the response. Is it possible to achieve this by any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure actually.
Rest-Assured makes you safer but not pointing to non-existent jsonpath, so I'd suggest to not waste a time for that.
Or either way - you can ask Backend devs to add that field explicitly in all responses even if it's not filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it checking whether the `f` key is available in each object of `values` array;

If it is available -> add the value of `address` in each object in `f` array, to a String list

If it is not available -> add `null` to the same String list.

I create a `org.json.JSONObject` from `io.restassured.response.Response`.

```
Response response = given()
        .when()
        .get(url)
        .then()
        .extract()
        .response();

List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<>();

JSONObject responseObject = new org.json.JSONObject(response.body().asString());
JSONArray jsonArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("values");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    if (jsonObject.keySet().contains("f")) {
        JSONArray fObjectArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("f");
        for (int j = 0; j < fObjectArray.length(); j++) {
            addressList.add(fObjectArray.getJSONObject(j).get("address").toString());
        }
    } else {
        addressList.add(null);
    }
}

System.out.println(addressList.toString());
```

This will print the following result;

```
[ffff, null, xxxx]
```

Comment: Thanks @kaweesha for the response